# Differences between concurrent and synchronized collections in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, collections, concurrency, synchronized

In Java there are

1. concurrent collections (e.g. `java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList`)
2. synchronized collections (e.g. `Collections.synchronizedList(List<T> list)`)

My insights so far:

- both types are thread safe regarding invoking their operations (`add()`, `get()` and so on)
- BUT: If you iterate over a Collection from type 2) it isn't thread safe at all (compare [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49490033/2438518)).Whereas iterating over a Collection of type 1) is thread safe.

Are there any other differences? And why has Java both types of collections? Wouldn't it be clearer to only have one type?